# How can I send a SELECT box selected "text" to a function on a button for ng-click using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

OK, I have this HTML page which contains a select element. That select element will have three choices (see the $scope definition below of those choices...:

```
<div id="mainID" ng-controller="theController">
    <form name="assetTypeForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate> 
        <select id="assetTypeSelect" name="asset.assetTypeList" style="width: 135px;"
            ng-model="asset.assetTypeList" 
            ng-options="option.name for option in assetTypeListOptions track by option.value"
            ng-change="regularAssetTypeToggleClick(asset)"
            class="form-control" required>
            <!-- This is a HACK to trick Angular to make the first option value = 0 -->
            <option value="" style="display: none;">Choose Type</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" 
                ng-click="createAsset({{asset.assetTypeList}});" //This is the value I'm trying to pass...
                class="btn btn-primary btn-small"> 
                Create Asset
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Next in my controller, I have this function called from the button:

```
$scope.createAsset = function (assetType) { //As you can see with assetType (arg) I want to pass what the user selected in the dropdown select box.

        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity');
        console.log("The asset I want to create is: " + assetType);

        if ($scope.assetTypeForm.$invalid) {

            console.log("BUMMER! The assetTypeForm is NOT valid: " + $scope.assetTypeForm.$invalid);
            $scope.submitted = false;
            return;

        } else {

            //Open the dialog for creating a graphic element
            $scope.openCreateElement(assetType);

        }

    };
```

I have the definition of the assetType drop down:

```
    $scope.assetTypeListOptions = [
        {
            name: 'Choose Type...',
            value: 'choose'

        }, {
            name: 'EULA',
            value: 'eula'

        }, {
            name: 'GRAPHIC',
            value: 'graphic'

        }];
    //This sets the default for the list
    $scope.assetTypeList = $scope.assetTypeListOptions[0];
```

What I get in the console.log is this:

```
The asset I want to create is: [object Object] <-- Here, is where either EULA, Graphic or Choose Type... where Choose Type... will throw an alert to tell the user, via show-errors{} that they NEED to select either EULA or Graphic.
```

That's it....

Thanks

OK UPDATE: In response the comment:

So, what you're saying is; I can pass what you suggested HERE: [[[ $scope.assetTypeListOptions[$scope.asset.assetTypeList].value ]]] into the function: "createAsset({{asset.assetTypeList}});" like this?

Comment: You are always can get `$scope.assetTypeListOptions[$scope.asset.assetTypeList].value`

Comment: Why use you `asset.assetTypeList` as a `ngModel`, but initialize `$scope.assetTypeList` instead?

Comment: to update: no, just use it in `createAsset` without any passing. It's already here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By order:

```
  ng-click="createAsset({{asset.assetTypeList}});"
```

You don't need to use `{{}}` in your directives:

```
  ng-click="createAsset(asset.assetTypeList);"
```

But you don't even need to pass it, because your select model always available as

```
$scope.asset.assetTypeList
```

---

Also you have wrong initialization:

```
$scope.assetTypeList = $scope.assetTypeListOptions[0];
```

You use `ng-model="asset.assetTypeList"`, so you should initialize:

```
$scope.asset.assetTypeList = $scope.assetTypeListOptions[0];
```

Be sure that `$scope.asset` initialized before.

Or otherwise, use `ng-model="assetTypeList"`.

Comment: Jim Dandy there sir!!! Works like a charm. Thank you!  PS - Jim Dandy is an old saying from the 20th century meaning: AWESOME or something to that effect. Bottom line. It works! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ng-model directive to apply the data binding.

So the "<   select>" became

```
 <select ng-model="fieldName" >
```

Then if the function that you need to call is in your controller, you can use $scope.fieldName to get the value of select.